# Copy result of a query to a new PostgreSQL database

Tags: postgresql, bulkcopy

I have a Postgres database A with 2 tables,  and I need to copy part of these tables (recent records in 1 month) to the new database with the same structures.

How to achieve this, as I know cross database references are not implemented. So I can't select records from the old database to copy to the new one.

I can code, so any ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Some ideas:

- You can use `COPY (SELECT ...) TO ...` to write the relevant parts of the tables to a file on the database server and use `COPY ... FROM` on the destination database to load the data.

  If the databases are not on the same machine, you could use NFS or similar for a shared directory, or you can use `COPY ... TO PROGRAM ...` to pipe the result into `scp`.
- You can use a `postgres_fdw` foreign table and just use

  ```
  INSERT INTO foreign_tab
     SELECT ... FROM localtab;
  ```

  to transfer the data.

Comment: I will try it tomorrow and feedback here. Thank you.